# cakephp 2.0 not working after uploaded on my server

Tags: cakephp-2.1

**In my localhost cakephp is working fine as like joomla i have uploaded by using filezilla but it is not working can any one tell me how to install it on server.**

Comment: you need to describe your problem better, give details about what is not working, and what were your procedures

Comment: check if permissions and user and group on files are set correctly.The tmp files should be 777.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to no exactly whats going wrong, as you haven't supplied much information!

So I take it you developed your application on your localhost, and then just uploaded the files to your web server using FileZilla.

Some things you're going to want to check:

1) Have you updated your app/Config/core.php file to adapt to your new database?

2) Have you created a new database on your web server, with the same fields/and or data that you had on your localhost server?

3) This is a given, but is your web server's database setup correctly? Does the user have access to the database?

Hope this helps,

Adam.